# Query running tally of open issues on a given day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have been banging my head on this for a while now and I think I've drastically over-complicating things at this point. What I have is a table containing the fields

- OpenDate
- ClosedDate
- Client
- Contract
- Service

What I need to turn that into is

- Date
- Client
- Contract
- Service
- OpenedOnThisDay
- OpenedYesterday
- ClosedOnThisDay
- ClosedYesterday
- OpenAtStartOfTomorrow
- OpenAtStartOfToday

For any given Date, there may or may not be any issues opened or closed ON that day. That day should still be included with 0's

I have come at this a number of ways and can produce one of the desired results at a time (opened on, closed on, Open at end of), but I cannot get them all at once, at least not without exponentially increasing the query time.

My queries currently as views are as follows

Opened On

```sql
select Cast(EntryDateTime as Date) as DateStamp
  ,ContractNumber
  ,Client
  ,services.Service
  ,sum(1) as Count
  ,lag(sum(1)) OVER (
    partition by tickets.ContractNumber
    ,services.Service ORDER BY Cast(EntryDateTime as Date) ASC
    ) as CountDayBefore
from v_JiraImpactedServices as services
LEFT JOIN v_JiraTickets as tickets ON services.ticketnumber = tickets.TicketNumber
WHERE tickets.Client is not null
  AND tickets.TicketNumber IS NOT NULL
  and tickets.ContractNumber is not null
GROUP BY Cast(tickets.EntryDateTime as Date)
  ,tickets.ContractNumber
  ,tickets.Client
  ,services.Service;
```

Closed On

```sql
select Cast(ResolvedDateTime as Date) as DateStamp
  ,ContractNumber
  ,Client
  ,services.Service
  ,sum(1) as Count
  ,lag(sum(1)) OVER (
    partition by tickets.ContractNumber
    ,services.Service ORDER BY Cast(ResolvedDateTime as Date) ASC
    ) as CountDayBefore
from v_JiraImpactedServices as services
LEFT JOIN v_JiraTickets as tickets ON services.ticketnumber = tickets.TicketNumber
WHERE tickets.Client is not null
  and tickets.TicketNumber is not null
  AND tickets.ContractNumber is not null
GROUP BY Cast(tickets.ResolvedDateTime as Date)
  ,tickets.ContractNumber
  ,tickets.Client
  ,services.Service;
```

Open On

```sql
SELECT calendar.FullDate as DateStamp
  ,tickets.ContractNumber
  ,tickets.client
  ,services.Service
  ,IsNull(count(tickets.TicketNumber), 0) as Count
  ,IsNull(lag(count(tickets.TicketNumber), 1) OVER (
      partition by tickets.ContractNumber
      ,services.Service Order By FullDate ASC
      ), 0) as CountDayBefore
FROM v_Calendar as calendar
LEFT JOIN v_JiraTickets as tickets ON Cast(tickets.EntryDateTime as Date) <= calendar.FullDate
  AND (
    Cast(tickets.ResolvedDateTime as Date) > calendar.FullDate
    OR tickets.ResolvedDateTime is null
    )
LEFT JOIN v_JiraImpactedServices as services ON services.ticketnumber = tickets.TicketNumber
WHERE tickets.Client is not null
  AND tickets.ContractNumber is not null
GROUP BY calendar.FullDate
  ,tickets.ContractNumber
  ,tickets.Client
  ,services.Service;
```

As I said each of these by itself gives ALMOST the desired results, but omits days with 0 values.

Aside from producing days with 0 values, I need to also combine these into a single table result. All attempts so far have either produced obviously wrong JOIN results, or takes an hour to execute.

I would be most grateful if someone could point me in the right direction here.

Comment: You say that you want to see a 0 when nothing occured on a certain day, but I think that you have to become clear on what Client, Contract and Service you want to see for each day (and where that information should come from when "nothing occured"). If you want to CROSS JOIN your calendar with the tickets or even with all possible combinations of Clients, Contracts and Services and maybe use *conditional aggregation*, you have to be aware of that the query won't be fast.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Each client has one or more contract numbers, and each contract has one or more services. What I need is for example if there is
Company A, Contract 123, Service ABC, 10 opened on 1/1, 0 opened on 1/2, 5 opened on 1/3, I need that 1/2 entry to be there. Services are fairly arbitrary between clients. In terms of speed, I can get by with narrowing it to a moving 60 day window, with an ideal target of 30s or less. This would be for a synced dataset and not run on demand so it doesn't have to be super fast, it just can't take 5's of minutes..

Comment: I could also accept a method of building a table that can be incrementally updated to use as my data source. But have not yet come up with a merge (or set of them) that is practical.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea, although the fieldnames don't match your scenario, this is how I would approach this:

```
WITH 
    SourceData (ClientID, ContractID, ServiceID, DateStamp) AS (
        SELECT a.ID, b.ID, c.ID, d.DateStamp
        FROM clients a
            JOIN contracts b ON a.ID = b.ClientID
                JOIN [services] c ON b.ID = c.ContractID
        CROSS JOIN calendar d
        WHERE d.DateStamp >= DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE())
    )
SELECT d.DateStamp, s.ClientID, s.ContractID, s.ServiceID
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN Cast(EntryDateTime as Date) = d.DateStamp THEN 1 END) AS OpenedOn
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN Cast(ResolvedDateTime as Date) = d.DateStamp THEN 1 END) AS ClosedOn
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN Cast(ResolvedDateTime as Date) > d.DateStamp OR ResolvedDateTime IS NULL AND EntryDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS InProgress
FROM SourceData s 
  LEFT JOIN tickets t
  ON  s.ClientID = t.ClientID
  AND s.ContractID = t.ContractID
  AND s.ServiceID = t.ServiceID
  AND s.DateStamp >= Cast(EntryDateTime as Date)
  AND (s.DateStamp <= ResolvedDateTime OR ResolvedDateTime IS NULL)
GROUP BY d.DateStamp, s.ClientID, s.ContractID, s.ServiceID
```